# Placeresult object returned from an autocomplete getPlace() call is missing several properties

Tags: google-maps, autocomplete, google-maps-api-3, google-places-api

When calling autocomplete.getPlace(), the PlaceResult object that is returned is now missing formatted_phone_number, international_phone_number, rating, and website properties. When I do a console.log of the place object this is what is returned:

```
Object
address_components: Array[8]
formatted_address: "Google Sydney, 5/48 Pirrama Rd, Pyrmont NSW 2009, Australia"
geometry: Object
html_attributions: Array[0]
icon: "http://maps.gstatic.com/mapfiles/place_api/icons/geocode-71.png"
id: "20074bf275d0d9476ed98e17445c8c19531e0c20"
name: "Google Sydney"
reference: "CnRlAAAASdbJCc7CCRHiL1gb7Z7BwJ9dLXhM16AexHOmugvvuC9t4o_RqKpgrq57CkIjS_YO7iCHtmypMjOFCkhc4zBGF882PHQW4Bv2rHEvePPfIrjWxT4VjYF7N-5SveVoPT7xe-jfWzH7YZDWeDxKyYFE2xIQJQb58Lr_dkmCmYVATfeObBoU1SmGG30mBXMR4TavRMo9XZNX8L4"
types: Array[2]
url: "http://maps.google.com/maps/place?ftid=0x6b12ae37b47f5b37:0x8eaddfcd1b32ca52"
vicinity: "Pyrmont"
__proto__: Object
```

Notice how the properties mentioned above in the Placeresult are no longer there. These properties were definitely showing in a Placeresult from an autocomplete.getPlace() call last week or so. Placeresult objects from a service.getDetails() are correctly returning all the properties mentioned in the Places V3 API, however a .getPlace() call is now missing these attributes despite referencing the same Placeresult. Any idea why these properties are now missing?

code:

```
  function initialize() {
    var mapOptions = {
      center: new google.maps.LatLng(-33.8688, 151.2195),
      zoom: 13,
      mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    };
    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map_canvas'),
      mapOptions);

    var input = document.getElementById('searchTextField');
    var autocomplete = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(input);

    autocomplete.bindTo('bounds', map);

    var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();
    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
      map: map
    });

    google.maps.event.addListener(autocomplete, 'place_changed', function() {
      infowindow.close();
      var place = autocomplete.getPlace();
      console.log(place);
      if (place.geometry.viewport) {
        map.fitBounds(place.geometry.viewport);
      } else {w
        map.setCenter(place.geometry.location);
        map.setZoom(17);  // Why 17? Because it looks good.
      }

      var image = new google.maps.MarkerImage(
          place.icon,
          new google.maps.Size(71, 71),
          new google.maps.Point(0, 0),
          new google.maps.Point(17, 34),
          new google.maps.Size(35, 35));
      marker.setIcon(image);
      marker.setPosition(place.geometry.location);

      var address = '';
      if (place.address_components) {
        address = [(place.address_components[0] &&
                    place.address_components[0].short_name || ''),
                   (place.address_components[1] &&
                    place.address_components[1].short_name || ''),
                   (place.address_components[2] &&
                    place.address_components[2].short_name || '')
                  ].join(' ');
      }

      infowindow.setContent('<div><strong>' + place.name + '</strong><br>' + address);
      infowindow.open(map, marker);
    });

    // Sets a listener on a radio button to change the filter type on Places
    // Autocomplete.
    function setupClickListener(id, types) {
      var radioButton = document.getElementById(id);
      google.maps.event.addDomListener(radioButton, 'click', function() {
        autocomplete.setTypes(types);
      });
    }

    setupClickListener('changetype-all', []);
    setupClickListener('changetype-establishment', ['establishment']);
    setupClickListener('changetype-geocode', ['geocode']);
  }
  google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
```

Comment: This is a know issue and we are working to fix this ASAP. The issue has been submitted on the issue tracker here: http://code.google.com/p/gmaps-api-issues/issues/detail?id=4016 Please click the 'star' icon to be notified of future changes.

Answer (score 0):

The Places-API is still experimental, so when you say last week you got the phone-numbers it may be that they changed something.

But however, you're right, what you get is a placeSearchResponse and not a placeDetailsResponse(what ist should be).

Comment: even a placeSearchResponse contains a rating property, but my object does not contain one:

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/places#place_search_responses. 

At least now I know it isn't just me! Thank you for your help!